# CSS header positioning

Tags: html, css

Just a quick question:

I have this html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="header">
   <div id="navbar">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    height: 120px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

My header (red container is stretched from left to right 100%) but I want it to be in a middle width given width; Help me please =)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "in a middle width given width".

Comment: It's already in the middle o_O

Comment: @bookcasey i think he meant "i want it to be in the middle with given width"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the css in

```
 #header{ margin:0 auto;}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cHKF4/)

Comment: i reduced the width of #header in fiddle so that you can easily see

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to do

```
#header {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

That'll center the div horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do

```
#header{margin:0 auto;}
```

Or

```
#header{position: absolute; left:50%; margin-left: -480px;}
```